# O "ajuda", "termos e políticas" são requisitos funcionais ou não funcionais?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, documentação

Minha dúvida é exatamente essa se o ajuda é um requisito funcional ou não em um sistema, já que ele após ser clicado traz uma seria de strings e formatações.

Comment: Meio ampla a pergunta, de qq forma eu entendo que o "sistema de documentação" (clicar, ler, paginar, armazenar no DB) é o recurso funcional, e o conteudo não.

Comment: Em tese então e funcional! O Bacco tu poderias responder ao invés de comentar, assim eu poço marcar como solução e de qualquer forma esperarei um pouco mais para ver se aparece outra resposta para a questão. Valeu!